# Kohana 3 - How to I18n-ing Form fields that are populated by the database?

Tags: php, database, internationalization, controller, kohana-3

I have something like a contact-form in my Kohana 3 app. Now what the customer wants to have is a select-field which gives the customer the chance to select his/her country.
That could be pretty easy. But the customer wants to have control over the countries which are included. So I chose for the database-way to do it.
I have a database table countries that has fields like 
code, title
'de', 'Germany'

Now I want these values to be i18n-ed in my form.
Anyone knows the answer?

Comment: I'm guessing you mean you want to be able to change the form labels and other text based on the user's language selection?

Answer (score 0):

Ok I just figured out a solution.
I figured out that the second parameter in an array (the value) doesn't need to be a string object. So I just made it an i18n kohana object.
Now everything works as expected.
Thanks anyway!

If you guys wanna see a code example. Just comment on my solution.

Also if you guys know a better solution. Comment my solution.

Comment: Hey, you should share your code for everyone to benefit from it.

Comment: You're right Alejandro. But I'm sorry that I cannot share this one with you, because my laptop was fried a bit later and I was too lazy for backups. This won't happen again, for sure! ;)